# Data populated wrongly in DataGridView

Tags: c#, windows, forms, datagridview

I have a DataGridView that is populated using a list.
During Runtime, the user can filter the data by entering data in a textbox. I am able to do the filtering part.

But the problem i am facing is when i change the datasource to the new datasource in the Textbox1_TextChanged event, the datagridview is populating the data with rows equal to the number of rows in my new datasource but each row is replica of the first row.

When I check the DataSource of the datagridview it has the data of the new DataSource.

So when I check the row selected in the datagridview_doubleclick event, the DataBoundItem gives me the exact object that it should give according the to new datasource.

What might have gone wrong??

Comment: Can you post some code ?

Comment: Are you filtering by way of changing the datasource?  Please post some code.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am wrong, but do you need to clear the DataGridView when binding to a new datasource.... my binding skills are lacking....

Try clearing the DataGridView, before changing the datasource like :

```
DataGridView.Rows.Clear();
```

Comment: Rows.Clear() throws an error.. But i made the DataSource for the datagridview as Null before assiging new datasource